# Best PHP Mail class

Tags: php, oop, class, email

I've been using php's mail function for years and decided it was finally time to make my code a bit more Object Oriented rather than writing out the code each time.

I was going to build my own mailer class but I figure there must be a ton of great classes out there already.  I started looking and got a bit overwhelmed by the choice so I thought it was a good question to put to SO

**Can anyone recommend their favourite/best php mail class?**

I'm just using it to send plain text email right now but will be shortly switching to html formatted emails so something that can grow with me would be best.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SwiftMailer or PEAR Mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293866/php-swiftmailer-or-pear-mail)

Comment: [`If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here`](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: There seem to be a lot more classes than just SwiftMailer and Pear so I thought I would ask the broader questions

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize "opinion" questions are not allowed.  Where is a good place to ask these types of questions?

Comment: You might get a better response over at http://www.programmers.stackexchange.com, although it's arguably still a little subjective for that - I don't know how kindly people will take to me directing you off Stack Exchange, but I have found some good advice over at http://phpbuilder.com/board/ in the past - which is set up as more of a forum, so "what is you opinion of _____" type threads are a bit more welcome there.

Answer (score 12):

We have been using PHPMailer for nearly a decade with no problems:

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

It has some nice features, such as good email validation (a harder problem to solve than it seems), and converting your HTML to human-readable plain text, with very nice ascii formatting for headers, tables, etc.